# How to make long headings easy to copy inside a card?

Tags: tooltips, overflow, title, cards

[image]

When somebody hovers on the heading "**Thanksgiving**", the full text appears as tooltip. The problem here is the Heading must be easy to copy so that user can send it to another user for particular purpose instead of typing himself/herself.

What would be usable solutions in favor of users?

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be a 'share' function on the card?

Comment: Long press desire text to make it select is default interaction anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicolas, Since the name is easily understandable including that three dots (ellipses), any person working within an organisation should understand the heading (in your case it looks like holiday name). There should not be any cognitive load in new person
So I must say "you are **overthinking** this problem."

If you put copy icon as suggested by jamesy, my question to you where do you put that copy icon in case of short headings.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a custom tooltip so you could include a copy feature or as the styling of the card resembles the material design metaphor, I've added an icon to the action row. The icon I've created is the one seen on the old Nokia windows phone interface for copy 'n paste.

[image]

You'd need another tooltip on hover over the icon indicating what the action does e.g. Copy the heading

Comment: Oh that will be touch **friendly** too. btw what is that copy icon for _in bottom_ of left card?

Comment: Yes hadn't considered touch devices. So the icon in the bottom left was a backup idea in case the user didn't hover over the heading. As soon I designed it, though I thought – what is this actually copying? Probably needs a label added for explanation.